# Connection refused: localhost:23177 MVC Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am trying to create an MVC 5 application using Visual Studios 2015 and keep getting the following error message:

> Connection refused: localhost:23177

I have Googled it with little help. One post suggested that i repair my visual studios which I did and it work but it was just a temporary fix. In case you need more information, I am currently following a code first approach to building my db.

Answer (score 0):

After 4 days trying to figure out what the issue is causing my connection to be refused is due to recently downloaded update 3 which probably got corrupted during installation. Since am using a local connection I was checking into it and download the IIS 10.0 Express  from :

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264.

I hope this helps any one with the similar problem.